# how can I use my cPanel server as my local dns server

Tags: dns, cpanel

I'm a web master, with a dedicated server running cPanel. I'm constantly editing my /etc/hosts on my local development machines so I can access sites on the cPanel server that aren't public yet. Is there a way I can use my cPanel server as my local networks dns server so that it will check that first to see if a site exists on my cPanel server before going out to the next name-server.  I tried just adding it as one of my nameservers, but that doesn't seem to work, so I assume I have to allow this kind of behavior on the server.

Comment: Do you have a fixed public address on your local router

Comment: @Paul my cPanel server is a normal public cPanel server, what does having a fixed ip on my local router have to do with it? I'm not trying to use cPanel to do resolution to local machines, I'm trying to have all DNS requests look at my public server to find a match before looking at any other dns'

Comment: Questioning the reason for a question is helpful.  Because the DNS in cpanel is not a public resolver. One approach would be to make it one, which would not be a clever move.  The other would be to restrict what remote parties can use it for resolution - that would require you to have a fixed IP.

Comment: I'd actually prefer it to be public unless there is some exploits that haven't been dealt with. That would work really well for me for several other reasons.

Comment: Making it public can be problematic. It's one more thing to maintain, and in light of the DNS poisoning drama we've had in the last few years, I'd motivate for a restricted access if you do want to use it at home.

Answer (score 0):

In your local network settings set the DNS server ip to the cPanel server IP's.

NOTE: Your cPanel IP's should be first and then add the public DNS servers.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/change-tcp-ip-settings